# Can I determine if I have been pinged?

Tags: programming

I have a project using a Wemos D1 Mini.  Is there a way for the sketch running on the Wemos to know when it's been pinged?

Comment: I am sure there is. But, what do you mean by "pinged"? Are you doing something with radar or sonar or ethernet? What have you done so far and what exactly did not work (I.e. what did you expect to happen and what actually happened)? It will also probably help if you posted a minimal example of code that recreates the problem. Please refer to the [Tour](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour)....

Comment: I assume you mean if you have received (and responded to) an ICMP PING packet...?

Comment: you can't at Arduino level. deeper may be, but I don't see anything related in the SDK API

Comment: I don't know if LWIP (leightweight IP stack) is built from source or provided as a binary blob for the Arduino ESP8266 core.. This is where you would handle ping requests / responses. Maybe it's also possible via LWIP APIs which hook these calls? Anyway it's for sure possible in the esp-open-rtos SDK (which build LWIP from source so you can also modify it)

Comment: just use http instead. you can curl it from the command line just like a ping.

Comment: Dandavis: ?? I don't understand.  I have a device that it on the local WiFi.  I want it to respond to a ping with an LED or bell or some other notification.  I think juraj had the correct answer.